# Share found, but no ShareSecurity

Tags: windows, powershell, security, share, get-wmiobject

I found a list of Windows shares using this cmdlet:

```
gwmi -Class win32_share -ComputerName blah
```

However, when I use the below cmdlet, it does not show the security setting for ALL shares:

```
gwmi -Class Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting -ComputerName blah
```

I can see the share w/ the missing security via the Server Management console.  Can anyone help?  thx!

NOTE: There's a huge discrepancy between the number of record returned from win32_share and win32_logicalsharesecuritysetting.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?  If it's a recent one, you might want to look at the _SmbShare_ cmdlets.  For example: `Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess`

Comment: I am using 4.0...and yes, Get-smbshare and access are available...thx!  btw, you might want to post this as a solution, so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using WMI classes directly is to use the *SmbShare* cmdlets.  For example, the following will list all of the share permissions on the local machine (can also work remotely):

```
Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess
```